# How to change directory of where temporary files are stored

Tags: filesystem, directory, tmp

I'm trying to move my temp directory from `home/user` to the `/tmp` directory in root.

I've tried using `export TMPDIR=/tmp` but it defaults back to my home directory after reboot.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/tmp` by default? what is the output of `$TMPDIR` after a reboot without setting it?

Comment: `$TMPDIR` returns nothing. @Ravexina

Comment: What about: `TMP` and `TEMP` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect earlier. `$TMP` returns nothing, `$TEMP` and `$TMPDIR` returns a new line (with nothing in it).

Comment: Can you tell where exactly temp file are being stored right now? the exact directory structure... so we might be able to search for them in configuration files to find out what and where it is being set.

Comment: It seems that there are systemd files in `/tmp` (of root) but for a lot of my applications, the files are being dumped in `/home/user*`. There are also systemd files in `var/tmp`.